# Proving $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x + \sqrt{x}) - f(x)=0$ if $|f'(x)|\le \frac1x$ for $x > 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Given a differentiable function ${\rm f}:\left(1,+\infty\right) \to \mathbb{R},\quad$ and
$\quad\left\vert\,{\rm f}'\left(x\right)\,\right\vert \leq \frac1x\,,\ \forall\ x>1$.

$$
\mbox{Prove that}\quad
\lim_{x \to +\infty}\left[\vphantom{\Large A}%
{\rm f}\left(x + \sqrt{x\,}\,\right) - {\rm f}\left(x\right) \right]=0
$$

Comment: Why did you ask the same question twice?! That's rude towards the volunteers that answer your questions!

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{|(f(x+\sqrt{x})-f(x))|}{\sqrt{x}}\le\frac{1}{x},\forall x>1$$\ \Rightarrow|(f(x+\sqrt{x})-f(x))|\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

you get 1. inequality after the mean value theorem

then you can take the limit

let $x>1$ and consider the open interval $(x,x+\sqrt{x})$

then the differential is bounded above by ($\frac{1}{x}$ because $|f'(x)|\le\frac{1}{x}$ and $|f'(x+\sqrt{x})|\le\dfrac{1}{x+\sqrt{x}}$, so which is bigger ?), by the MWT the differential quotient is also bounded.

Comment: That's true but I suggest you to explain it in little bit more details.

Comment: @lnwvr:No, not necessarily.

Comment: @derivative how you got your first inequality?